# Next cell on Union range VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Need a help to find the next cell in the union ranges without a loop.
For now, it's works for me with a loop.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Set op = Union(Range("A1", "A2"), Range("A4", "A5"), Range("A9", "A10"))
    If Not Intersect(Target, op) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each cell In op
            If te = 1 Then
                cell.Select
                Exit Sub
            End If
            If cell.Address = Target.Address Then
                te = 1
            End If
        Next cell
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End Sub
```

I didn't find how I get cells in range without "For Each Cell In Range".
And didn't find how I know whats a number of selected cell in my specific union range.

What I need to do is to find the next cell within the union that is immediately after the cell whose edit was detected by the `Worksheet_Change`.

Comment: _"next cell"_ with respect to what? what's `te`? You'd better give more details about your overall goal

Comment: What about `ActiveSheet.Cells([RowIndex], [ColumnIndex])`?

Comment: I changed cell in my union area, and need to selected next cell on the union.
For example if my range =Union(Range("A1", "A2"), Range("A4", "A5"), Range("A9", "A10"))
and I changed the "A2" cell, I need to select next cell in the union - "A4".
If I changed "A5" I want to find "A9" cell.

How I can use for this the [RowIndex], [ColumnIndex]?

Comment: "te" is a notification that I edited previous cell, and the next cell that what I need

Answer (score 0):

Look into Cell Protection. On a Protected Sheet, the User has access to only Unlocked, i.e., Locked = False, cells.

Thus, if an edit is made to an unlocked cell the next unlocked cell will be selected.
This requires the following additional settings:

All cells defined by your Union have their Protection set to Locked = False.
All non-Union cells have their Protection set to Locked = True (This is a default setting anyway).
File -> Options -> Advanced -> checkbox "After pressing Enter, move selection". (This too is a default setting.)